# Accessing row and column from a single dimension array

Tags: php, c, arrays, optimization

I recall being able to do something like this from a long time ago in an algorithm class, but I think I may just be imagining it.

Say we have the following 3x3 table

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

That can be stored as an array (0=>1, 1=>2, ..., 8=>9)

I can lookup the value of row 1, column 1 (0 indexing, so the value 5) using some math.  Assuming we know the width of the table.

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
```

`array(width * row_val_lookup + col_val_lookup)`

Since width = 3, we want row 1, and col 1, then that is `array( 3*1 + 1 = 4 )` which is right.  I think?

I'm trying to expand on this for lookups into tables that are also subgrouped.

```
+----------+----------+
|  0  1  2 |  3  4  5 |
|  6  7  8 |  9  A  B |
+----------+----------+
|  C  D  E |  F 10 11 |
| 12 13 14 | 15 16 17 |
+----------+----------+
```

So I am trying to come up with an equation that will let me look at all the values in block 0 (1,2,3, 6,7,8), or block 1 (3,4,5, 9,A,B), block 2 (C,D,E, 12,13,14) or block 3 (F,10,11, 15,16,17)

We know the total width is 6, we know the width of each block is 3, and the height of each block is 2.

```
arr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17);
arr_length = 24; // total length
tw = 6 // total width
bw = 3 // block width
bh = 2 // block height
bpr = tw / bw // blocks per row = 2
bro = tw * bh // block index row offset = 12
```

I need to be able to look through all values in a block, all values in a column, and all values in a row.  So I think I need 3 loops.

```
// check row, left to right
for (i=row_to_check; i<(row_to_check + tw); i++) {
    if(check(arr, i) == FALSE)
        break; // exit loop if we met a false condition
}

// check col, top to bottom
for (i=col_to_check; i<arr_length;) {
    if(check(arr, i) == FALSE)
        break; // exit loop if we met a false condition
    i += tw; // col + total width
}

// this is where i'm confused (two loops???)
// need to find starting index, then we can just use the tw offset to scoot down in the block
// first row of blocks is just block_number * block_width, but we don't know where blocks fall down to the next row
// so we need to find out what row the block is on
// total_width / block_width = number of blocks per row
// total_width * block_height = index offset per row of blocks (block 2 starts at index C)
// block 0 and block 1 are block_row 0, block 2 and block 3 are block_row 1
// if we use integer division for the blocks...
// 0 \ num_blocks_per_row = 0
// 1 \ num_blocks_per_row = 0
// 2 \ num_blocks_per_row = 1
// 3 \ num_blocks_per_row = 1
// offset from start of block_row = 3 % num_blocks_per_row = 1
// Sooo...  block 3's index = (block_number / (total_width / block_width))*(total_width*block_height) + (block_number % (total_width / block_width) ) * block_width = (3/(6/3))*12 + (3%(6/3))*3 = 3/2 + (3%2)*3 = 1*12 + 1*3 = 15
// DAMN that's messy
// using new variables that I set up upstairs
// starting_index = (block_number / bpr) * bro + (block_number % bpr) * bw
// check block (only have bw*bh values to check?)
for(i=0; i<(bw*bh); i++) {
    for( ) {

    }

}
```

I know it's a lot of stuff and I've put some thought into it, but just can't seem to figure it out in my head.  I was hoping someone else might just be better at this than I am.

Comment: yes, two nested loops.

Comment: also, if its php, you are missing `$` in your var names.

Comment: Good question. It's got me thinking.

Comment: Haha thanks MightyPork, I have just been writing pseudocode for this stuff (closest to PHP/C)

Comment: I guess there needs to be a way to lookup what the starting index is for a given block.  Block 0 starts at index 0, block 1 at index 3, block 2 at index C, block 3 at index F.  Almost like `(TotalWidth / BlockWidth) ... something something` Also, apologies for using hexadecimal, been using it a lot in assembly lately.

Comment: Are you sure that `block 0 (1,2,3, 7,8,9)` is right? Shouldn't it be `block 0 (0,1,2, 6,7,8)`?

Comment: You're absolutely right!  I hope that's the only place I messed up on, that could cause chaos for other calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will return the indices of desired elements in the one dimensional array:

```
function getIndices($rows, $columns, $subMatrixRows, $subMatrixColumns, $subMatrixIndex) {
    $indices = array();

    // LiCol coordinates of submatrix 
    $subRow = ceil($subMatrixIndex * $subMatrixColumns / $columns);
    $subColumn = ($subMatrixIndex -1 ) % ($columns / $subMatrixColumns) + 1;

    // LiCol coordinates in global matrix of first sub matrix element
    $baseRow = ($subRow -1 ) * $subMatrixRows + 1;
    $baseColumn = ($subColumn -1) * $subMatrixColumns + 1;

    // Index in zero based one dimention array of first sub matrix element
    $baseIndex = ($baseRow - 1) * $columns + $baseColumn - 1;

    // Indices in zero based one dimention array
    for ($i = 0; $i < $subMatrixRows; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $subMatrixColumns; $j++) {
            $indices[] = $baseIndex + $i * $columns + $j;
        }
    }

    return $indices;
}
```

Tested with following results:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    print_r(getIndices(4, 6, 2, 3, $i+1));
}

    Array
(
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 6
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 8
)
Array
(
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 9
        [4] => 10
        [5] => 11
)
Array
(
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 13
        [2] => 14
        [3] => 18
        [4] => 19
        [5] => 20
)
Array
(
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 16
        [2] => 17
        [3] => 21
        [4] => 22
        [5] => 23
)
```

Comment: This seems very close to what I need it for.  Thank you!  I'll have to mess around with it for a while.

Comment: Okay, so I see this gets the indices in a given block, which is what I was getting stuck on.  I think I may format my other functions to return arrays like you have as well to generalize the process of checking.  Thanks!